# SetText String[] in a TextView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use `setText`, and I want to use a `String` array. First, I create a `String []`, then I assign data to `String[0]`, then I want to `.setText(String[0])` on my `TextView`, is this the right way? 
Note : I'm using a StringTokenizer to split Strings in the textfile

```
  try {
    filename = "myk.txt";
    FileReader filereader = new FileReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +      "/Q/" + filename);
    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(filereader);


      try {
        while ((text = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(text);
            sb.toString().split(";");
            tokens = new StringTokenizer(sb.toString(), ";");

            ///NULLPOINTER EXEPTION HERE//// if (tokens.countTokens() > 0){questionfromfile[0] = tokens.nextToken();
            }


        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 ////ETC ...//// and now textview.setText(question[0]);
```

Comment: It should work, but if you won;t show us your code, we won't be able to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you mean something like

```
String[] strings = new String [5];
strings[0] = "foobar";
component.setText(strings[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you have this line:

```
sb.toString().split(";");
```

?

are you forgetting that a string is immutable ,meaning that using the standard API that you use , the string will never change itself , but create new objects instead?

about StringTokenizer, as [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) say:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
>   reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
>   that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String
>   or the java.util.regex package instead.